# Create Environment Python-3.5 Errors

Tags: python-3.x, installation, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda (that installs Python 3.6) within Windows 10...and it worked fine.  I then tried to create a Python 3.5 environment:

% conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda

But the process *fails* on verification.  I've tried twice...and the verification lists 702 errors as below... Here are the top three (I've substituted 'UserName' for my user name):

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at C:\Users\

```
<UserName>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\pyqt-5.6.0-py35hd46907b_5
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Enginio.pyd'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\pyqt-5.6.0-py35hd46907b_5
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Enginio.pyi'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for pyqt located at C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs\pyqt-5.6.0-py35hd46907b_5
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/QAxContainer.pyd'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.
```

This should be straightforward:  install an environment, within Windows 10... 
Yet it fails... is there a step I've missed? path variable unset?

Comment: Try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/66084/88005

Answer (score 25):

have same issue. And helped with this [link](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4429).
`conda clean --packages --tarballs`

Answer (score 13):

Just another alternative to the previous answer:

```
conda clean --all
```

This removes index caches, lock files, unused cache packages, and tarballs.